# Cannot search newly created files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

#### Scenario

I am using Visual Studio Code to work on a project, say it's path is `/project/`. i.e. I opened VSCode -> Open Folder -> Selected `/project/`.

And when I am working on the project, there are some intermediate files created by running some program (For example unzipping a zip file).

So a lot of files are created and placed under `/project/temp/`.

#### What I expect

When I press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F`, I can also search for files in `/project/temp/`.

#### What I observed

I can only search for files in `/project/*` except `/project/temp/`.

But if I opened another VSCode Window -> Open Folder -> select `/project/temp/`, I can then search for those files.

How can I achieve my expected behavior, without opening 2 VSCode windows?

Answer (score 0):

On the Search side bar, below the search field, there is a three dot menu (...).
There you will find a field called `files to exclude`, that has a gear button to the right. That button is `Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files`.
See if unchecking that helps.

If that doesn't work or is already unchecked, you can try reloading the vs code window:

> press `ctrl + shift + p`, type `reload` and select `Developer: Reload Window`